Finding the multiplicative inverse of $a^{-1}+b^{-1}$ in a non-commutative ring R, given that $a,b,$ and $a+b$ are invertible elements in R.
Here is the full question: Let R be a non-commutative ring and suppose $a, b,$ and $a+b$ are all invertible elements in R. Show that $a^{-1}+b^{-1}$ is invertible and find its multiplicative inverse.
This is a question that I am really struggling to come up with an answer for in my abstract algebra class. Let me just preface this by saying that so far, the only things we have covered regarding rings is the properties that a set must satisfy to be a ring, and we have gone over a few examples of different types of rings, for example that the set of 2x2 matrices with real number entries is non-commutative. But not much more has been covered regarding rings and we are studying rings before groups, in case that makes a difference.
Here is what I’ve come up with so far regarding this problem:
I know that since R is non-commutative, then $ab \neq ba$. I also know that since $a, b,$ and $a+b$ are invertible elements, that $aa^{-1}= 1, bb^{-1}=1,$ and $(a+b)(a+b)^{-1}=1$.
For the part of the proof where I need to show that $a^{-1}+b^{-1}$ is invertible, what I was thinking of doing is using the given information that since $a, b,$ and $a+b$ are invertible, then $a^{-1}, b^{-1},$ and $(a+b)^{-1}$ are all elements of R. Then since $a+b$ is invertible we can say $a^{-1}+b^{-1}$ is invertible. But I’m wondering now if that is accurate.
Then as far as finding the multiplicative inverse of $a^{-1}+b^{-1}$, I am completely stuck. I have been messing around with the equation $(a^{-1}+b^{-1})x=1$ and somehow trying to solve for $x$ by replacing $1$ with $aa^{-1}$ or $bb^{-1}$ and so on but have not been able to come to any conclusions by doing this. I have also tried discussing with my classmates and it seems like we are all struggling on this problem.
Also, I tried thinking about a specific example to help me out with this. An example of a non-commutative ring we have gone over in class is the set of 2x2 matrices with real number entries. I know that two matrices $A$ and $B$ are invertible and I can find their inverse, and then add them together to get another 2x2 matrix that is also invertible… but I don’t know how to relate that to this problem since we are not talking about that ring specifically.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!!

You have not proven that $a^{-1}+b^{-1}$ is invertible; what you say does not show that.
